# How do you search a Model's attributes of type 'array'

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a `Model`, `Pet`, with an attribute `favoriteFoods`.

```
// Pet.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        favoriteFoods: {
            type: 'array'
        }
    }
};
```

`favoriteFoods` is stored as an `array`, because it's a free-text field for the user.

Now, is there a way to `find` based on values of that `array`?

I'm actually interested in querying from the URL, the following example DOES work, but it's not ideal.

`/pet?where={"favoriteFoods":{"contains":"Best Food"}}`

Is there a better way? A string comparison doesn't seem like the best solution.

For example, if one example entry has `favoriteFoods: ["Best Food", "Best Treats"]` and another has `favoriteFoods: ["Second Best Food", "Best Treats"]`, then the `query` above will return 2 results. Our goal is a result w/ an exact match to one of the entries in the array, so this does not give us the intended result.

Comment: You should update your question with the concerns of your current solution and what you would want from a solution to get the best answer.

Comment: It's normal use-case when you send `where` criteria in HTTP request.

Comment: @Meeker - added an example. Let me know if you'd like more.

Comment: @ghaiklor - can you expand on what you mean? I don't quite follow.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, although maybe not the most performant is to simply encapsulate in quotes. The following would find `"Best Food"` and not `"Second Best Food"`

`/pet?where={"favoriteFoods":{"contains":"\"Best Food\""}}`

Sub-document queries are being implemented in the next version of waterline. Your other other option would be to go `native` or `query` depending on your adapter.

In this instance your adapter would make the biggest difference.